# Operating system on Atmel 328 Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano

Is it possible to use some sort of multitasking OS like ScmRTOS on Arduino based on Atmel 328 chip?

Answer (score 2):

You can use FreeRTOS on the AVR family:

- http://www.freertos.org/a00098.html

Comment: I tried it and it works. However, it turned out to be not very useful in the end. The Arduino Due or Arduino Zero with the schedular is a lot more fun.

Comment: Here is a portable implementation of the Scheduler https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Arduino-Scheduler.